# How to display the file a match was found in using get-content and select-string one liner

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to search a directory of perl scripts and compile a list of all the other perl scripts executed from those files(intentionally trying to do this through Powershell).  A simplistic dependency mapper, more or less.

With the below line of code I get output of every line where a reference to a perl file is found, but what I really need is same output AND the file in which each match was found.

```bsh
Get-Content -Path "*.pl" | Select-String -Pattern '\w+\.pl' | foreach {Write-Host "$_"}
```

I have succeeded using some more complicated code but I think I can simplify it and accomplish most of the work through a couple lines of code(The code above accomplishes half of that).

Running this on a windows 10 machine powershell v5.1

Comment: If you want to simplify it... `Select-String -Path "*.pl" -Pattern '\w+\.pl'`

Comment: You're right.  That works better.  I wrongly assumed I needed to start with Get-Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do things like this all the time.  You don't need to use get-content.

```
ls -r *.pl | Select-String \w+\.pl

file.pl:1:file2.pl
```

Comment: Thanks.  That got me to the next step where I can now display each property separately:
```Get-Childitem *.pl | Select-String \w+\.pl | foreach {write-host "filename is $($_.filename). match is $($_.matches.value)"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `ls` or `Get-ChildItem` either; `Select-String` can take a path parameter:

```
Select-String -Pattern '\w+\.pl' -Path *.pl
```

which shortens to this in the shell:

```
sls \w+\.pl *.pl
```

(if your regex is more complex it might need spaces around it).

For the `foreach {write-host` part, you're writing a lot of code to turn useful objects back into less-useful strings, and forcibly writing them to the host instead of the standard output stream. You can pick out the data you want with:

```
sls \w+\.pl *.pl | select filename, {$_.matches[0]}
```

which will keep them as objects with properties, but render by default as a table.

Comment: Get-childitem is nice for a recursive search.